# How to create extra padding between keyboard and edittext in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is my code;

```
Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), Alignment.BottomCenter) {
    TextField(value = "Test", onValueChange = {})
}
```

I want to extra padding between keyboard and edittext;

[image]

Comment: My bro there is always an indian tutorial on the youtube :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8waTylS0wUc&t=120s&ab_channel=SimplifiedCoding

Comment: please read this doc https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/&ved=2ahUKEwjb_aiW9ub6AhUHDOwKHWMaD0wQFnoECBYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1bFmMRxkdpSG2GjvyMua6b